# my vscode emmet not work since last update

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

Exclamation mark ! for html template not work in my vs code since the new update ,
and some others emmet like li*5 not work.
I also reinstalled it but nothing fair with it.
So , anyone check it.